# Undefined offset And Array Comparison PHP

Tags: php, arrays, comparison, undefined, equality

Hey everyone ive done my research and i find im still stuck many people said to put @ sign before the variable but it does not seem to be working, so my code gives me this error

```
                 Notice: Undefined index: 2 in login.php on line 20
```

my code is

```
          if( isset($_REQUEST['email']) || isset($_REQUEST['pwd']) || $_REQUEST['email'] != "" || $_REQUEST['pwd'] != "" )
                    {

                          $inputFile = fopen("members.txt", "r");  
                          $found = false;
                          $i =0;
                          //read the read.txt until the end of file
                          while(!feof($inputFile) && $found == false)  
                          {

                            $line = fgets($inputFile);  
                            // replace the special charater within the lines by there proper entity code
                            $lineArray = preg_split("/\,/", (string)$line);


                            if ($_REQUEST['email'] === $lineArray['2'] && $_REQUEST['pwd'] === $lineArray['4']) 
                            {
                                        session_start();
                                        $found = true;
                                        $useremail=$_REQUEST['email'];
                                        $password= $_REQUEST['pwd'];
                                        //time to set sessions and stuff
                                        $_SESSION['useremail'] = $useremail;
                                        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                                        //send the redirect header
                                        header('Location: index.php');
                                        exit();
                            }
                          }
                          fclose($inputFile);

                    }
```

so the line its referring to is

```
                            if ($_REQUEST['email'] === $lineArray['2'] && $_REQUEST['pwd'] === $lineArray['4'])
```

ive tried many other variation such as removing single quotes adding @ in front of the $lineArray and doing both, can anyone help me out the values are there when i was printing them out but when it get to this if statement it doesn't turn to equal and it give me this error.

if also tried

```
           if ($_REQUEST['email'] === $lineArray[2] && $_REQUEST['pwd'] === $lineArray[4])
```

and

```
        if ($_REQUEST['email'] === @$lineArray[2] && $_REQUEST['pwd'] === @$lineArray[4])
```

Comment: do not use `$_request` better go for `$_get` or `$_post`

Comment: echo contents of $line and tell us what it gives

Comment: another wired thing is that if i place 
                              $lineArray[2] = "try";
  $lineArray[4] = "try"; 
before the if and enter try and try within the text boxes it works so i just dont get why its doing this ?

Comment: @mithunsatheesh --------LineArray------Array ( [0] => kunal [1] => kunal [2] => kunal [3] => kunal [4] => 123456789 ) --------Line ------kunal,kunal,kunal,kunal,123456789 --------LineArray------Array ( [0] => kunalM [1] => KunalM [2] => kunalM [3] => kunalM [4] => kunalkunal ) --------Line ------kunalM,KunalM,kunalM,kunalM,kunalkunal --------LineArray------Array ( [0] => ) --------Line ------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means there is a undefined var being used in your code. In your case, it's talking about `$lineArray['2']`. This isn't a serious error, so you can be lazy and alter your error settings to get rid of it:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

But you really should just fix it instead.

As Devnate suggested, you need to use a int to specify the index key of the array, instead of a string (so this `$lineArray[2]` instead of this `$lineArray['2']`). Why? Because the key you was using before ('2') was never set, which resulted in the error.

You say the comparing fails when you attempt the above. I cannot help you with that until I see the result of `print_r($lineArray);`.

This is the code from your previous question. It's a shame you didn't take my advice and go with my code. You wouldn't be having this issue if you did. But that's a different matter. Post the `print_r($lineArray);` so I can see what the problem is with the comparing.

Comment: hey the lines are like noted above to be --------LineArray------Array ( [0] => kunal [1] => kunal [2] => kunal [3] => kunal [4] => 123456789 ) --------Line ------kunal,kunal,kunal,kunal,123456789 --------LineArray------Array ( [0] => kunalM [1] => KunalM [2] => kunalM [3] => kunalM [4] => kunalkunal ) --------Line ------kunalM,KunalM,kunalM,kunalM,kunalkunal --------LineArray------Array ( [0] => ) --------Line ------

Comment: Right. So when you say the comparing doesn't work, have you tried `echo`ing `$_REQUEST['email']` to see why there is no match?

Comment: hey i found out it was cause i was entering a \n which added a space in the end you were right!!

Answer (score 2):

You need `$lineArray[2]`. Indices of an array are integers, not strings. And also ensure if that same array has atleast 3 elements.

---

The line is the problem:

```
$lineArray = preg_split("/\,/", (string)$line);
```

It should be (since you seem to be splitting on `,`):

```
$lineArray = preg_split("/,/", (string)$line);
```

---

PS: Consider using a simpler [`$array = explode(",",$yourString)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Hey ive tried that like i mention up above i originally had it as so, but the it doesn't seem to be equal even when the data is the same, also i get the undefined error still.

Comment: This did not work either when i originally print my $line i get 
First Line give me : kay,kay,kay,kay,123456789 Second Line gives me : kay,kay,kay,kay,passw

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `print_r($lineArray)` and `print_r($line)`

Comment: --------LineArray------Array ( [0] => kunal [1] => kunal [2] => kunal [3] => kunal [4] => 123456789 ) --------Line ------kunal,kunal,kunal,kunal,123456789 --------LineArray------Array ( [0] => kunalM [1] => KunalM [2] => kunalM [3] => kunalM [4] => kunalkunal ) --------Line ------kunalM,KunalM,kunalM,kunalM,kunalkunal --------LineArray------Array ( [0] => ) --------Line ------

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use numbers (no quotes) for your array keys, but you'll also need to check that those array values exist with `isset()` before comparing them.

```
if (isset($lineArray[2]) && $_REQUEST['email'] === $lineArray[2] ...
```

Comment: Hey i changed my code to this, it did stop giving me the error but it does not match my values when its comparing.